# Where can I find a MIDI file for Max Kortlander's "Russian Rag"?

Tags: electronic-music, instrumental, piano, sound, audio-software

A pianist myself, I like how this song sounds and want to learn how to play it. Since there is no sheet music for this song, I've been looking for a file that I can convert into music. Can someone help me?

P.S. It's not George Cobb's version that I'm looking for. Only Kortlander will do.

Comment: MK was very involved with the QRS company, who look to be keen on preserving their player-piano legacy.  Have you made enquiries there ?  [QRS music](https://www.qrsmusic.com/music.asp?cid1=28).  [This article](http://ragpiano.com/comps/kortland.shtml) claims that some of the piano rolls are available as MIDI from QRS

Comment: @Angst Thank you very much! They said that they would get back to me soon. I can't believe that I never thought to go to the publishing company.

Comment: if it turns out ok, you will be able to answer your own question ! I'm interested by your question - does the Kortlander version differ from the version credited to Cobb ?

Comment: Their melodies are very similar. Kortlander's version is a more sophisticated pianola spin-off of Cobb's easy ragtime piece.